# How to create new projects in Eclipse using Maven 3 archetypes

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-3

Is there some plugin for Eclipse which allow me to create new projects based on Maven 3 archetypes? I have to deal with a bunch of archetypes (including some created/used internally by our organization) and would like to have some plugin which e.g. would ask me

- which archetype to use
- what is the group id
- what is the artifact id

and the would create a project with that information. However, this seems impossible.

So, there are two questions:

- is there such a plugin? If so,
- *how to use it in a way analogous to the one I described below?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/)?
I believe it covers all your needs. Once installed you can create a new maven project and the wizard will ask you for archetype, group and artifact id.

Just go to `File-> New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven Project` and it will guide you.

**Note**: the 2 on the m2eclipse doesn't need it uses maven 2, you can configure it to use any maven installation that you may have